# Malloc'd char array has unexpected output

Tags: c, printf, malloc, valgrind

My problem is simple, **I don't understand why this program doesn't output correctly :**

```
int size = 35;
// malloc size for text
char *txt = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
if(!txt) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation for text data failed.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for each character in text
    txt[i] = 'a';
}
printf("%s\n", txt);
free(txt);
```

**Expected output :**

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

**Actual output :**

> aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa8 9 10 1 0 
>   12 11 6 37 44 3 45 56 0 64 77 5 68 83 0 
>   39 46 0 19 16 9 8 2 6 3 1 4 17 12 9 
>   17 6 0 25 10 3 31 16 13 21 9 9 11 7 4 
>   2 3 0 7 6 1 9 5 2 11 2 5 19 6 13 
>   21 8 15 8 0 0 7 0 0 29 20 13 62 50 0 
>   49 35 0 41 27 1 38 25 9 25 13 0 21 11 0 
>   24

---

**Tried debugging** with `valgrind --leak-check=yes`, the only error it shows is the following :

> ==3999== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
>   ==3999==    at 0x4C30F78: strlen (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>   ==3999==    by 0x4EA969B: puts (ioputs.c:35)
>   ==3999==    by 0x400B39: main (decode.c:85) // this is the printf line

I thought it was because it didn't know when to stop printing, but I tried :

```
while(txt != NULL) {
    printf("%c", *(txt++));
}
```

And I also tried :

```
txt[size - 1] = '\0';

while((*txt) != '\0') {
    printf("%c", *(txt++));
}
```

Those gave even worse results where it would fill my console with special characters.

Comment: You seem to forget that `char` strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** byte strings*. That *null-termination* part is important. Once you do that you can print it as a string. Also note that it means that a string of 35 characters needs space for 36 characters to fit the terminator.

Comment: `malloc(size * sizeof(char *));` you want 35 chars, not 35 char pointers.

Comment: Oh and by the way, `malloc(size * sizeof(char *))` allocates enough memory for `size` *pointers* to `char`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `\0` in the char array. Otherwise `printf` will have `undefined behavior`.

Also in `malloc` you are allocating for `char` not `char*`.

#### Example

```
int size = 35;
// malloc size for text
char *txt = malloc((size+1) * sizeof(char ));
if(!txt) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Allocation for text data failed.\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
memset(txt,0,size+1); 
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for each character in text
    txt[i] = 'a';
}

printf("%s\n", txt);
free(txt);
txt=NULL;
```

1. Alternatively one can set `txt[size]='\0'` also because all other position are overwritten with characters inputted. [**Peter** commented this]

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! As I specified at the end of my post, I also tried to add '\0' in the char array and didn't get much luck with it. I tried with sizeof(char) without the * and got segmentation fault. Can you provide a working example ?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand: You can check the example

Comment: wow, I see my mistake now, thanks a lot again. Only tried with a while(*(txt) != '\0') with %c, and not simply with %s. Is memset essential there ?

Comment: @PaulLemarchand.: Just zeroing out the char array..you can do it other way also

Comment: Instead of `memset(text, 0, sizeof(text))` before the loop, one could do `txt[size] = '\0'` after the loop.   The loop is overwriting `txt[0]` to `txt[size-1]` anyway, so no need to `memset` those.

Comment: yes @Peter ...That's exactly the thing...I told the OP also..As you said,,I will edit it. I just gave a quick answer which will ensure correctness...will edit. Thanks for suggestions

Comment: `sizeof(text)` is incorrect. `text` is not even declared.  If you meant `sizeof(txt)`, that would be the wrong size.

Comment: It's even worse now. `sizeof(txt)` is the size of a pointer. The right size would be `(size+1)`. But you should use `calloc` if this is your intent

Comment: @M.M.: I missed that it is a pointer where I have dynamically allocated. Yes calloc is an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
int size = 35;
// malloc size for text
char *txt = malloc(size * sizeof(char *));
```

You have not malloc'ed 35 bytes, but instead 35 pointers (i.e. 140 bytes on 32-bit or 280 bytes on 64-bit).

This should be 'malloc(size * sizeof(char))' or just malloc(size).

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for each character in text
    txt[i] = 'a';
}
```

You've initialized only the first 35 of 140 or 280 bytes allocated.
You haven't null terminated your string.

```
printf("%s\n", txt);
```

Now you are printing a string that isn't null terminated and valgrind
has correctly warned you that it is accessing uninitialized memory when
trying to perform strlen() on the input txt.

Answer (score 0):

`char *txt = malloc(size + 1);`
...

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { // for each character in text
    txt[i] = 'a';
}
txt[size] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", txt);
```